# How to connect to database with Python and iODBC under Linux?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, iodbc

I would like to connect to a database with Python through **iODBC** under Linux (Ubuntu).

I installed packages **iodbc** and **libiodbc2-dev**.
And I installed the driver for my database (a **HFSQL** Classic database from **PcSoft** (french solution)).

Then I can connect to my database with `iodbctest` (a C program from **iodbc**) with success.

Now I would like to connect with Python 3.

I tried **pyodbc** and **pypyodbc** modules, but they are linked to use **unixODBC** (libodbc.so), not **iODBC** (libiodbc.so).

How can I connect with Python to my database through **iODBC** under Linux (Ubuntu) ?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to a database with Python using iODBC on Linux (Ubuntu), you can use the `pyodbc` module with a few extra steps to make it work with iODBC. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Install `pyodbc` using pip:

```bash
pip install pyodbc
```

2. Configure iODBC driver for your database:
   You mentioned that you have already installed the driver for your HFSQL Classic database from PcSoft. Make sure it is correctly configured in the iODBC configuration file (`odbcinst.ini`). You can typically find this file at `/etc/odbcinst.ini`.
3. Configure your data source in the iODBC configuration file (`odbc.ini`):
   Create or edit the `odbc.ini` file, typically located at `/etc/odbc.ini`, to define your data source. The data source is the connection information needed to connect to your database. Here's an example of how the `odbc.ini` might look like:

```ini
[MyDataSource]
Driver=TheDriverNameInOdbcInstIni
Database=YourDatabaseName
Server=YourDatabaseServer
```

Replace `MyDataSource`, `TheDriverNameInOdbcInstIni`, `YourDatabaseName`, and `YourDatabaseServer` with the appropriate values for your setup.

4. Set the `ODBCINI` environment variable:
   To make sure `pyodbc` uses the correct iODBC configuration files, you need to set the `ODBCINI` environment variable to point to your `odbc.ini` file. You can do this in your Python script or set it globally for your system. For example, in your Python script:

```py
import os

os.environ['ODBCINI'] = '/path/to/your/odbc.ini'
```

Replace `/path/to/your/odbc.ini` with the actual path to your `odbc.ini` file.

5. Use `pyodbc` to connect to your database:
   Now you should be able to use `pyodbc` to connect to your HFSQL Classic database using iODBC. Here's a basic example:

```py
import pyodbc

connection_string = 'DSN=MyDataSource;UID=YourUsername;PWD=YourPassword'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)

# Now you can use the 'conn' object to execute SQL queries and interact with the database.
```

Replace `MyDataSource`, `YourUsername`, and `YourPassword` with the appropriate values for your database connection.

With these steps, you should be able to connect to your HFSQL Classic database from Python using iODBC on Linux (Ubuntu) with the `pyodbc` module.